# Has anyone been able to schedule an automation through SSJS yet?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, ssjs

I was wondering if anyone has been able to **schedule** an automation with SSJS yet?

I tried, and given an existing automation "automation", already created in SSJS, I have the script below:

```
if(automation.Status == 2) {
    // Create Recurrence Definition
    var Recurrence = Platform.Function.CreateObject("DailyRecurrence");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Recurrence, "DailyRecurrencePatternType", "Interval")
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(Recurrence, "DayInterval", 1)

    // Create Schedule Definition
    var scheduleDefinitionApiObj = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ScheduleDefinition");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "CustomerKey", automation.CustomerKey);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "Name", automation.Name);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "StartDateTime", "2018-05-30T10:00:00-05:00");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "EndDateTime", "2018-06-01T10:00:00-05:00");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "RecurrenceType", "Daily");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "RecurrenceRangeType", "EndOn");

    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(scheduleDefinitionApiObj, "Recurrence", Recurrence);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(automation, "Schedule", scheduleDefinitionApiObj);
}
```

However, the last line of this script is giving me the following error:

> SetProperty only works for objects in the ExactTarget.Integration.WSDL
>   namespace. Object Type:
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   Property Name: Schedule

I cannot get my head around this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.